# How to plot data from a list?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am filtering a list of data. I need to plot my results per source node. This is a pattern of my data:

```
 ('timestamp', 'node_source', 'node_destination', 'node_source_counter_acces_to_specific_function')
```

In the plt.xlabel I want to put the timestamp. In the plt.ylabel I want to put the counter. In the legend, I want to put marker based on destination adress. Every line is my dataset  is very important. I am using this function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list_info= [('1547977394', '02141592cc0000000100000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '1'),
('1547977395', '02141592cc0000000100000000000000', '02141592cc0000000300000000000000', '2'), 
('1547977396', '02141592cc0000000100000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '3'), 
('1547977397', '02141592cc0000000100000000000000', '02141592cc0000000700000000000000', '4'), 
('1547977398', '02141592cc0000000100000000000000', '02141592cc0000000300000000000000', '5'), 
('1547977399', '02141592cc0000000100000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '6'), 
('1547977400', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '7'),
('1547977401', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '8'),
('1547977402', '02141592cc0000000200000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '9'),
('1547977403', '02141592cc0000000100000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '10'),
('1547977404', '02141592cc0000000200000000000000', '02141592cc0000000300000000000000', '11'),
('1547977405', '02141592cc0000000400000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '12'),
('1547977406', '02141592cc0000000300000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '13'),
('1547977407', '02141592cc0000000400000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '14'),
('1547977408', '02141592cc0000000400000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '15'),
('1547977409', '02141592cc0000000300000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '16'),
('1547977410', '02141592cc0000000400000000000000', '02141592cc0000000300000000000000', '18'),
('1547977411', '02141592cc0000000200000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '19')]
```

For example, the expected data that must be plotted and visuliazed to `node_source:02141592cc0000000100000000000000`  are:

```
('02141592cc0000000100000000000000',timestam':[1547977395,1547977396,1547977397,1547977398,1547977399,1547977403],'Counter':[2,3,4,5,6,10],'dest':[02141592cc0000000300000000000000,02141592cc0000000500000000000000,02141592cc0000000700000000000000,02141592cc0000000300000000000000,02141592cc0000000500000000000000,02141592cc0000000500000000000000])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plots = dict()

# create dictionary like this: plots[source]={'timestam': list of integer timestamps, 'counter': list of integer counter, 'dest': list of destinations}
for i, el in enumerate(list_info):
    if el[1] in plots:
        plots[el[1]]['timestam'].append(int(el[0]))
        plots[el[1]]['counter'].append(int(el[3]))
        plots[el[1]]['dest'].append(el[2])
    else:
        plots[el[1]]={'timestam': [int(el[0])], 'counter': [int(el[3])], 'dest': [el[2]]}

# iterate over elements in 'plots', sort by timestamp, plot
for i in plots:
    y = [x for _,x in sorted(zip(plots[i]['timestam'],plots[i]['counter']))]
    labels = [x for _,x in sorted(zip(plots[i]['timestam'],plots[i]['dest']))]
    x = sorted(plots[i]['timestam'])
    plt.plot(x, y, label=', '.join(labels), marker='o') # label=... creates the legend entry
plt.xlabel('timestamp')
plt.ylabel('counter')
plt.title('some data')
plt.legend() # add legend
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: result]

(The sorting is not necessary if your `list_info` is already sorted by timestamps.)

Edit:

```
# iterate over elements in 'plots', sort by timestamp, plot
f, ax = plt.subplots(len(plots), 1, sharex=True)
for i, item in enumerate(plots):
    y = [x for _,x in sorted(zip(plots[item]['timestam'],plots[item]['counter']))]
    labels = [x for _,x in sorted(zip(plots[item]['timestam'],plots[item]['dest']))]
    x = sorted(plots[item]['timestam'])
    ax[i].plot(x, y, c='k') # label=... creates the legend entry
    for j, _ in enumerate(x):
        ax[i].scatter(x[j], y[j], label=labels[j])
    ax[i].legend() # add legend
    ax[i].set_ylabel('counter')
plt.xlabel('timestamp')
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. But I need to have subplots in  every figure i represent source adress , in the legend I put  destination. The way you present data  precisely legend makes the analyziz of the figure very complicated.

Comment: @dina see edit. However, this is not really how SO is supposed to work. You should at least post what you tried to show your effort..

Comment: I put my data and results that I have their  in a new question 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54298370/how-to-make-plots-based-on-list-of-information-in-python

Comment: I would be very grateful if you help me.

Comment: @dina did you see that I added something to my answer? Is that what you wanted?